# Is there any other effecint way to put delays in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer, nstimer

I am doing the core animation. Here my `CALayer` wants to pause and resume more than 5 times during animation. Currently i am using `[Self performSelector: afterDelay: ]` and Timers to implement delays. For implementing now i am using 5 timers , i think it's bad style of coding i am using. So is there any other better way to implement the delay.

Now i am doing the `pictureBook` while reading the text i have to move an image along with it. It's successfully implemented. But to adjust the movement of image according to the voice over, i have to pause the layer and resume it according to voice played. For every page i have six languages too, so the delay are different for every languages , Likewise i am having 20 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit animations and the [`CAKeyframeAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class with its timing functions to define the animation and its timing more precisely.

See also the [Core Animation Cookbook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_Cookbook/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005406) (especially the dedicated "Timing" section) and the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514) in Apple's documentation.